# Vickrey vs English Auction Equivalence

Tags: game-theory, finance

Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_auction#cite_ref-2):

> When the auction involves a single item for sale and each participant
> has as an independent private value for the item auctioned, the
> expected payment and expected revenues of an English auction is
> theoretically equivalent to that of the Vickrey auction, and both
> mechanisms have weakly dominant strategies.[1] Both the Vickrey and
> English auction, although very different procedurally, award the item
> to the bidder with the highest value at a price equal to the value of
> the second highest bidder.[2]

In an English auction, the object goes to the highest bidder who pays at the price they proposed.

In a Vickrey auction, the object goes to the highest bidder, who pays at the *second-highest price.*

Given this, how are they "equivalent" to each other? The only thing common between the two, per my understanding, is that the highest bidder always wins.

---

My guess is that, in an English auction, when the second-highest bidder eventually places a bid (say `b0`) corresponding to their max affordable value, the highest bidder can place another bid ever so slightly higher (say `b1`). The object is then sold at `b1`.

In a Vickrey auction, the highest bidder would pay `b0`.

Since `b0` is almost equal to `b1`, I imagine that's where the equivalence comes from.

Comment: That's correct. A couple of nuances: in some English auctions, the auctioneer can choose the increment by which to raise the price. The greater this increment, the greater the theoretical difference with a Vickrey auction. Also, although the outcome is effectively the same, an English auction gives you information about the other players' values; this could be useful if there are multiple items for sale, for example. In a Vickrey auction, the bids are private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the Vickrey auction, each bidder is bidding their value (since it is a closed auction), whereas in the English open auction, the winning bidder has bid a price just at-or-above the second-highest value (instead of bidding their value which is the highest).