# Revenue Equivalence in Auction Theory: how does an English auction generate the same revenue as First Price Sealed Bid?

Tags: finance, auction-theory

The [theroem](https://www.econport.org/econport/request?page=man_auctions_revequiv):

> The revenue equivalence theorem states that, if all bidders are
> risk-neutral bidder and have independent private value for the
> auctioned items, then all four of the standard single unit auctions
> have the same expected sales price (or seller's revenue).The four
> standard single unit auctions are the English auction, the Dutch
> auction, first-price sealed-bid auction, and the second-price sealed-bid
> auction.

Given the preconditions, how is it possible for an English auction to genereate the same revenue as a first-price sealed auction?

Per my understanding, an **English auction**, when played optimally, [generates the same revenue as a second price sealed auction (Vickrey auction)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985087/vickrey-vs-english-auction-equivalence).

On the other hand, a **First Price Sealed Bid**, when played optimally, results in a revenue equivalent to the highest bid.

So how can the two be revenue equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, if one person bids 10\$, another 20\$, and a third one 30\$, then it seems that first-price auction would result in 30\$ and second-price in 20\$. However, under different rules -  that are of course known in advance - the participants would make different bids. E.g., under a second-price auction, you tend to bid more than what you are willing to pay because that's not what you are going to pay. Then again, you won't bid *that* much more and risk the second-price be above your original evaluation.  This may explain how the "obvious" difference is not that obvious after all. But can we expect in this scenario that the  second-highest price is much higher than what the second bidder estimates? Shouldn't they - by the same argument - bid more than 20, but only slightly more, perhaps 22\$ (so still way below 30\$)?

The key part in the full theorem is also that it is about "privately-known signal[s] independently drawn from a **common** strictly-increasing, atomless distribution" (emphasis mine). So it is not the case that one participant *inherently* values the object more than the others. I didn't look up the proof though, but under these circumstances, it doesn't look that much infeasible any more.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand the last paragraph. How does that precondition make it possible for a an English auction to be revenue equivalent to  a second price sealed bid?